# Results from a DialogFragment to an ActivityFragment

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-fragmentactivity

I have a `DialogFragment`, that depending on how it's called, will either pop up a dialog, or start an Intent, based off of results from the `dialogFragment`. Essentially, my `DialogFragment` is a list of activities, which depending on how I call I will want more information about the activity, or to start the activity. Ideally, I would like to have something akin to the `onActivityResult` to handle these results, in my base class. Doing some research has indicated that if I was using a Fragment, instead of a `FragmentActivity`, I could use the `DialogFragment.setTargetFragment()` method, but that won't work for a `FragmentActivity`. Any other suggestions on what I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: Create an interface to receive the data from the Dialog. Pass the appropriate class to the Dialog, and let each function decide what it is going to do.

```
public interface ListViewDialogReceiver {
    abstract void OnListViewDialogReceived(FragmentActivity activity,AbstractItemType itemSelected);

}
```

Other than that, it's merely creating an appropriate instance of ListViewDialogReceiver, to call the class.

After thinking about this a bit, I could also simplify the interface, assuming that the class is created from the main function. Still, this interface gives me all of the flexibility I might need in the future to handle anything.